# Transfer WordPress Live site to Localhost

Tags: wordpress, wamp

I downloaded all files through FTP and pasted them in my 'www/mysite-live' folder.

I'm using WAMP. I did download the live SQL file and imported it via localhost/phpmyadmin.

I did change my wp-config.php configuration.

```
define('WPLANG', '');
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/mysite-live');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/mysite-live');

define('DB_NAME', 'mysite_db');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Now when i view `http://localhost/mysite-live/` I can only view the Homepage
I can't access the other Pages and Posts. I get 404.

What seems to be the problem. What did i miss?

Comment: Have you tried changing permalinks to default at `wp-admin > settings > permalinks`.

Comment: Are you using pretty URLs with `mod_rewrite` (removing `index.php`)? `mod_rewrite` has to enabled by hand in WAMP's `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes it's a permalink problem.. I was able to fix it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**go your wp-admin->setting->permalinks**

> save again your Common Settings as your live site.